# Why does my Java project can't read properties file created by Eclipse, but with Notepad or Visual Studio Code one?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, properties-file

I got a simple Java project to read properties file like this:

[This is project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwzpl.jpg)

This is PropertiesFileReader class:

```
public class PropertiesFileReader {
    
    public void propertiesFileReader(String key) throws IOException {
            
        Properties pro = new Properties();
    
        // solution 1
        File f = new File("./propertiesFiles/exampleByNotepad.properties");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
    
        // solution 2
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream("./propertiesFiles/exampleByNotepad.properties");
    
        pro.load(fr); // or pro.load(input);
        pro.setProperty("firstKey", "first Value");
    
        System.out.println(pro.getProperty(key));
    }

}
```

This is propertiesFileExecution class

```
public class propertiesFileExecution {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        PropertiesFileReader pfr = new PropertiesFileReader();
        
        pfr.propertiesFileReader("sayHello");
        pfr.propertiesFileReader("sayGoodbye");
        pfr.propertiesFileReader("myName");
        pfr.propertiesFileReader("firstKey");
    }

}
```

I created 3 properties files. One created by Eclipse (File-> New -> Other -> File), one created by Notepad (create example.txt first then change the extension), and the remain created by Visual Studio Code.

This is my properties file content.

```
# this is properties file
sayHello=Hello
sayGoodbye=Goodbye
myName=Ray
```

When I run, I only got right result with Notepad and VSC creating file.

But not with file created by Eclipse. When I load the Eclipse properties file.
With this code:

```
Properties pro = new Properties();
    
        // solution 1
        File f = new File("./propertiesFiles/exampleByEclipse.properties");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
    
        // solution 2
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream("./propertiesFiles/exampleByEclipse.properties");
    
        pro.load(fr); // or pro.load(input);
        pro.setProperty("firstKey", "first Value");
```

I will got this result:
`null null null first Value`

Another thing, I can open to edit properties file created by Eclipse, but can't do with other 2 files. These 2 files can be read and edited by Notepad, but Notepad can't read the Eclipse created file.

It takes me a day to realize this.

And I don't know why my Java project can't read properties file created by Eclipse?

Comment: "Notepad can't read the Eclipse created file.” What happens when you try to open the file in Notepad?

Comment: Properties files are just text files with different extension. You should be able to open it with any text editor, including Notepad++. My first guess would be that the file is locked by another process, maybe an antivirus or Eclipse itself. Try closing Eclipse, or event rebooting your machine and try re-opening the file with notepad.

Comment: If I open properties file created by Eclipse in Notepad, I just see alot NUL character between the alphabet character. Like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10wlb552Re7FcZkI7OPlsZ3r5GIy_ifqb/view

If I open properties file created by Notepad in Eclipse, I will see like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BjjJwkC6UAO3pFuMkxRfHHm7A-Avz50v/view

And my program can just read properties file created by Notepad.

Comment: What is the File Encoding being used by the properties file in Eclipse? Look at the "text file encoding" entry in the  "Resource" page of the "Properties" for the file.

Comment: Oh, text file encoding is UTF-32 (found by right click -> properties -> resources).  Then I change to UTF-8 and rewrite the properties file content. Then program now can read the Eclipse created file.
So the main reason is Eclipse set text encoding to UTF-32 automatically when I create file. But my program can only read the UTF-8 file.Thanks all of you!

Comment: Eclipse doesn't normally use UTF-32 automatically for anything. Check the default text file encoding in the "General > Workspace" page of the Preferences. Also the encodings in "General > Content Types"

Comment: yeah, I found that somehow the default encoding of Java properties file in Preferences -> General -> Content Types is UTF-32. That's why all properties file I had created before got UTF-32 encoding. Thanks!